# On touch of parent layout not responding

Tags: java, android

In my code i am implementing swipe on parent layout on touch of parent layout, There is also an on click listener on my child layout. Now because of this on click listener on the child layout, whenever i swipe on the parent layout it doesn't respond to the touch, but once i removed the on click listener of the child it started responding to the touch on parent layout. Anything do with my xml file.

This is my code snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_view_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_description_text"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/but_drag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_description_text" >
        </ImageView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_alarm_time_layout"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#dee2e8" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_alarm_clock"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/clock_top_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/image_alarmclock_compact_mode"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image_description_text"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" >
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image_alarm_clock"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image_description_text"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="gone" >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**On click of child layout**

```
text_alarm_time_layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    // Do something
                }
            });
```

**On touch of parent layout which is not responding if above call is there**

```
         image_view_layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of implementing the *OnClickListener()* to your layouts try doing this:

add these lignes to layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_view_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="image_view_layout_clicked"

    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
```

and in your activity add this function

```
 public void image_view_layout_clicked (View view)
{
    // Do something
}
```

and do the same thing with your child layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_alarm_time_layout"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="text_alarm_time_clicked" 

        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#dee2e8" >
```

and in your activity add this function

```
 public void text_alarm_time_clicked (View view)
{
    // Do something
}
```

so that when you click in your Relative layout in will automatically call its function

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If you look at android source of [View](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#8060) class you will notice that implementation of `View#onTouchEvent` will always [return true](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#8161) for Clickable views (View [becomes clickable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#4025) when you set onClick listener for it).

That means such View's [dispatchTouchEvent](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#7127) will return true, consuming touch event and therefore it will not be propagated to other views, including parent.

So, what you have is totally justified, just look into source to confirm yourself.

If you want both your child and parent to receive touch event in your case you could :

- instead of `onClickListener` set `onTouchListener` for you child (filtering `ACTION_UP` event) and return false
- Implement custom RelativeLayout for your parent container and implement [onInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) to get events before they are dispatched to your children
- You can also trigger `onClick` of you child from your parent' `onTouch` handler if you detect that touch event happened within child's boundaries :

```
    // on Touch for parent
    parent_layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { // click event
                Rect childRect = new Rect();
                child_layout.getHitRect(childRect);
                // check if event is within child's boundaries
                if (childRect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
                    child_layout.performClick(); // trigger child's onclick
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This way, child's `onClick` will happen *after* parent's `onTouch`

**Edit** : forgot to mention, for this hack to work you have to call

```
child_layout.setClickable(false);
```

*after* your setup your child's `onClickListener`, so it won't consume `onTouch` events you wish to receive by parent.

Comment: Actually i want onClickListener on child and onTouchListener on parent. But what you suggest is little confusing to me, because id i return false onTouchListener then it won't call ACTION_UP event. Can u show with an example

Comment: @Rahul I am going to have lunch and then come back

Comment: I provided a simple hack in my answer, please check

Comment: hey i just saw ur message. I will imlement it in my code and let u know

Comment: hey man, I fixed missing brace in my answer and also I forgot to mention that you have to call `child.setClickable(false)`, please see the edit. It works for me, just checked.

Comment: Please consider accepting/upvote if it worked or let me know if it didnt